# Write query in BigQuery from Pubsub

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

need some help.

I'm receiving messages with data in a PubSub topic, I need to insert the data I get from the message and query in BigQuery with a background cloud function(PUB/SUB)...

What I manage to do:

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.insertBigQuery = (message, context) => {
    extractQuery(message.data);
   
};

function extractQuery(pubSubMessage){
    // Decide base64 the PubSub message
    let logData = Buffer.from(pubSubMessage, 'base64').toString();
    // Convert it in JSON
    let logMessage= JSON.parse(logData);

    console.log(logMessage.customerToken)
    console.log(logMessage.fbclid)
    console.log(logMessage.fbc)
    console.log(logMessage.fbp)
    console.log(logMessage.firstHitTS)
    console.log(logMessage.consentFB)

    main();
    
    return logMessage

    }

"use strict";

function main() {
  const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
  const bigquery = new BigQuery();

  async function query() {
    const query = `INSERT INTO MYTABLE( customerToken, fbclid, fbc, fbp, firstHitTS, consentFB)
    VALUES ("customerTokenSCRIPTCLOUD","fbclidSCRIPT"," fbcSCRIPTCLOUD"," fbpSCRIPTCLOUD","2021-01-05",TRUE )`;

    const options = {
      query: query,
      location: "US",
    };

    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

    const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

    console.log("Rows:");
    rows.forEach((row) => console.log(row));
  }

  query();
}
```

Now every time I receive a message I query in bigQuery, but my VALUES is hard coded, as you can see here:

```
const query = `INSERT INTO devsensetestprojects.TestDataSet.fbSimpleData( customerToken, fbclid, fbc, fbp, firstHitTS, consentFB)
    VALUES ("customerTokenSCRIPTCLOUD","fbclidSCRIPT"," fbcSCRIPTCLOUD"," fbpSCRIPTCLOUD","2021-01-05",TRUE )`;
```

What I'm not able to do is to get the values from `function extractQuery(pubSubMessage)` and use them in my query the same way I use in the function (logMessage.SOMEVALUE) to have the correct values I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you are beginner in development. Here a more concise and efficient code. I didn't tested it but it is closer of what you want. Let me know is some part are mysterious for you!

```
// Make them global to load them only when the Cloud Function instance is created
// They will be reused in the subsequent processing and until the instance deletion
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery();



exports.insertBigQuery = async (message, context) => {

    // Decode base64 the PubSub message
    let logData = Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString();
    // Convert it in JSON
    let logMessage= JSON.parse(logData);

    const query = createQuery(logMessage)

    const options = {
        query: query,
        location: "US",
    };

    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

    // Only wait the end of the job. Theere is no row as answer, it's only an insert
    await job.getQueryResults();

}

function createQuery(logMessage) {
    // You maybe have to format correctly the logMessage.firstHitTS to be accepted by BigQuery as a date.
    return `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(customerToken, fbclid, fbc, fbp, firstHitTS, consentFB)
                   VALUES (logMessage.customerToken, logMessage.fbclid, logMessage.fbc, logMessage.fbp,
                           logMessage.firstHitTS, logMessage.consentFB)`;
}
```

Comment: "Error: Unrecognized name: logMessage at [2:15]
    at new ApiError (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:59:15)"
I have no idea why this is happening, it seems that logMessage still does not go through.
merci beaucoup ️

Comment: It seems that the problem is that in that part `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(customerToken, fbclid, fbc, fbp, firstHitTS, consentFB)
                   VALUES (logMessage.customerToken, logMessage.fbclid, logMessage.fbc, logMessage.fbp,
                           logMessage.firstHitTS, logMessage.consentFB)` every thing is a string and I need to use the variables, maybe is a syntax problem

Comment: Dear @guillaume blaquiere, your funcion was perfect! I just needed to change the `function createQuery(logMessage)` worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you change to fix it? NodeJS is my weaker language and I don't see immediately what's the problem!

Comment: I just changed the way of getting variables in the query string `queryString=“INSERT INTO \”MYTABLE\”(abc, def, ghi) VALUES ( @abc, @def, @ghi);` at the end I got something like that, now I’m in my phone, tomorrow I’ll comment the hole block! Merci Maître
Edit: was not a problem with the code itself the function is perfect it was the sql syntax.

Comment: Well, what did you change?