# Using data from HTTP request in cloud functions to query BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

need some help with Google Cloud functions.

I created a Cloud func that triggers from `HTTP` request, I'm an using GTM server-side `TAG` to send a `POST` request to my Cloud Function trigger, this request contains data in the headers and body, I need to use this data to query my BigQuery. I found some boilerplate code in google docs and tried in my function, but now when I send the `request`, the response is `500`.

What I have until now:

```
exports.parseXML = (req, res) => {
  // Convert the request to a Buffer and a string
  // Use whichever one is accepted by your XML parser
  const data = req.rawBody;
  const xmlData = data.toString();
  console.log('data' + data)
  console.log('xmldata' + xmlData)
  const {parseString} = require('xml2js');

  parseString(xmlData, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).end();
      return;
    }
    console.log('result' + result)
    res.send(result);
  });
};
```

I really thought that would be easier since I just need to access data from the `POST` request I'm sending from my `TAG`, does anyone have a better approach to or can help me to find a solution?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated,
Kind regards,

Comment: You get the raw data (in byte), transform them in String, parse the XML and read it. 3 steps, 3 lines. Not very boiler plate. Try this in Go or in Java!! :D

Comment: Dear @guillaume blanquiere, thank you so much for your comment, the problem is that I’m getting status 500 when I send a request. So my function is broken, do you know a easier way to read the data. From GTM I’m sending the headers and body as JSON, that’s why I thought it would be a better way to handle, can you guide me into a better solution?

Comment: What's you error? It's a parseString error? Is you XML valid? Do you have an issue locally or on Cloud Functions?

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere, sorry for the late comment, I solved the problem with the snippet you gave me in this [question]{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668300/write-query-in-bigquery-from-pubsub}, thank you so much for your support and patience!

Comment: @CaioCésarP.Ricciuti could you post the adapted solution proposed on your second question as an answer to this one? this would make it easier for other members of the community that are going through the same issue to find and apply it to their case. Also you can accept that answer and increase your reputation on StackOverflow. :)